# Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator on entire plane

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform, laplacian

According to the answers in the the following questions: [How to prove the spectrum of the Laplace operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790401/how-to-prove-the-spectrum-of-the-laplace-operator?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [What is spectrum for Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766479/what-is-spectrum-for-laplacian-in-mathbbrn%5D) , the spectrum of the Laplace operator $\Delta :H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)\subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is in fact $\sigma(\Delta)=(-\infty,0].$ However, I was not able to find a discussion on the eigenvalues of $\Delta$.

The set of eigenvalues $\sigma_p(\Delta)$ (also called point spectrum) is known to be contained in $\sigma(\Delta)$ and one can have $\sigma_p(\Delta)\subsetneq \sigma(\Delta)$. Indeed, by taking the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}:L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ of the eigenvalue problem one has
$$\Delta u(x) = \lambda u(x),\;\;\forall x\in \Bbb R^2 \;\;\;\overset{\mathcal F}{\longrightarrow}\;\;\;\;-4\pi^2|\xi|^2\hat u(\xi) =\lambda \hat u(\xi), \;\;\;\forall\xi\in \Bbb R^2,$$ and this can only be satisfied by $\hat u=u=0$. <s>This means that the only eigenvalue-eigenvector pair in this setting is $(\lambda,u)=(0,0)$</s> . Also, the same argument applies when $\Delta$ is seen as $\Delta:W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^2)\subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with $p\in [1,2)$ and $\mathcal F:L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)\to L^{p^*}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with $1/p+1/p^*=1$.

***Question 1***. *What happens when $p>2$ and the Fourier transform becomes distribution valued, so that the above elementary argument cannot be applied directly?*

It seems if $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is in fact an eigenvalue of $\Delta$, then it cannot be in  $L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for any $p\in [1,2]$. Depending on the answer to Q1, this might also hold for $p>2$. In any case, it seems that the $L^p$ framework is not suitable for this problem.

***Question 2***. *On what space(s) could one define the domain of $\Delta$ to obtain non-trivial eigenvalues?*

---

*Edit.* The crossed out sentence should be replaced by: "The point spectrum $\sigma_p(\Delta)$ is therefore empty."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point spectrum coincides with the spectrum minus 0 if $p>2n/(n-1)$ and it is empty in the remaining cases ($n$ is the dimension). This is proved in G. Talenti: "Spectrum of the Laplace operator acting in $L^p(R^n)$", Indam, Symposia Mathematica vol VII, Academic Press 1971.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. However, it remains to show that for $p>2n/(n-2)$ (so in our case $p>4$) and $\Delta:W^{m,p}\to L^p$ , the spectrum is still given by $\sigma(\Delta)=(\infty,0]$. I have a proof of this using the Fourier transform that works, but only for $1\leq p\leq 2$. However, in our case, we need to study the spectrum for $p>4$!

Comment: The full spectrum is in any case $(-\infty, 0]$, for every $p$. The inclusion in the half line follows from semigroup theory, since the heat semigroup is bounded holomorphic of angle $\pi/2$, the reverse inclusion by showing that negative numbers are approximate eigenvalues.

Comment: How is the heat semi-group defined?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm misunderstanding something - but $0$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $\Delta$ for any $p < \infty$ since the heat semigroup converges strongly to $0$ on $L^p$ (as $t \to \infty$) for every $p \in (1,\infty)$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I think I computed the Fourier transform properly, right? So where does this problem come from?

Comment: @UserA: I'm not sure I understand your question. What I wrote doesn't contradict your computation, does it?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Jochen you are right, the argument works for the spectrum minus 0. Of course, there is a way of avoiding semigroups. For $l\lambda$ not a negative number (and not 0), write formally the inverse through the Fourier transform and then use Mikhlin to check the boundedness. If $\lambda<0$ one shows it is an approximate eigenvlaue (the functions $e^{iax}$ should be an approximate eigenvector). For the point spectrum, one first show that if there is an eigenfuntions, then there is a radial one, by averaging, and then ends with a Bessel equation whose asymptotic is known.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: Thanks a lot for your reply, and for the explanation of how to construct the eigenfunctions! Quite embarrassingly for me, I really wasn't aware (before reading your post) that $\Delta$ has any point spectrum on $L^p$ for sufficiently large $p$)

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune does the paper you referenced have an English translation?

Comment: It is in English

Comment: @JochenGlueck neither was I and this is actually a remarkable property! On another another, I think I made a mistake by calling the trivial pair $(\lambda, \hat u)=(0,0)$ an eingenpair.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Since you are interested I go on. If $\Delta u+k^2 u=0$ ($K \neq 0$) and $u$ is radial, then setting $u(r)=r^{(1-n)/2}w(r)$ you get a Bessel equation whose solutions at infinity oscillate lile $\sin$. Then the asympotics for $v$ at inifinity is like $r^{(1-n)/2}$ which is in $L^p$ for $p>2n(n-1)$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I only found the Italian version on Springer. Any other place where I can download the paper?

Comment: I doubt, I have my personal copy

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I searched quite a lot and was not able to find Symposia Mathematica vol VII, Academic Press 1971 on Google. Do you have any idea where I can find it?

Comment: I checked better the book. Some papers are in italian but this one is in English. If you need I can scan and send a copy via mail. Then you should write to me via mail to giorgio.metafune@unisalento.it

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you very much! Email sent.